# By how much is a value of a struct pointer increased when adding 1 to it?

Tags: c

If I have the code on a 32-bit word machine:

```
struct myStruct {
//structure that occupies six bytes
uint32_t value1;
uint16_t value2;

} *p = (myStruct *)0x10;
```

How much does p++ equal? 0x14? 0x11? or 0x16?

Comment: You can easily check that yourself.

Comment: the only guarantee is that it will point to the next potential `myStruct`. The exact address, how many bytes the struct takes in memory, etc are specific not just to 32-bit but compiler and architecture.

Comment: It is hard to check since I don't know if the structure will occupy consecutive bytes, and whether it is a coincidence the fact that it has increased the size the structure might have. Also, since this is a pretty rare question around here I thought that having it posted for future reference couldn't hurt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is incremented by the sizeof(myStruct).  Pointer arithmetic is in units of the size of what is pointed at.  for char *, p++; p = p + sizeof(char);